# TypeScripts has no compile time error although wrong type is passed to method

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

**method call**:

```
  this.onChangeScoreGradeType(this.gradingKeyForm.get("scoreGradeType").value.key);
```

**method definition**:

```
onChangeScoreGradeType(scoreGradeType: KeyValue<string,string>) 
{

}

this.gradingKeyForm.get("scoreGradeType").value
```

is of type `KeyValue<string,string>`

Why occurs there no compile error, that

```
this.gradingKeyForm.get("scoreGradeType").value.key
```

which is a string does not fit into a `KeyValue<string,string>` instance?

What do I have to change in my TypeScript settings?

```
export default class KeyValue<TKey,TValue>
{
    constructor(public key: TKey,public value: TValue)
    {

    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `KeyValue`?

Comment: Sure... see my update!

Comment: [I have compile error...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20KeyValue%3CTKey%2C%20TValue%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20key%3A%20TKey%2C%20public%20value%3A%20TValue)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20onChangeScoreGradeType(scoreGradeType%3A%20KeyValue%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E)%20%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20KeyValue('test%20key'%2C%20'test%20value')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AonChangeScoreGradeType(test.key)%3B)

Comment: Cool... now I have to find out why my visual code editor with angular 4 + TS 2.2 does not fail! I have also added my tsconfig.json maybe you see sth wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `this.gradingKeyForm.get("scoreGradeType").value.key` the type is `TKey`. Generics become `any` if they cannot be inferred. Hence `key` is probably of type `any` which makes it compatible with everything.

Comment: Ok if I would do assigned the .value.key to a string variable and pass that one, that compilation fails because I inferred it :-) With C# I get compile errors about ' can not be infered...' too bad that TypeScript feels like a cheap copy of C#.